# SAP Analysis for Microsoft Office & R - How to extract SAP data straight into R?

Tags: r, excel, automation, extract, sap-analysis-for-office

I'm using SAP Analysis for Microsoft Office to extract data from SAP system into Excel ([SAP Help Portal > Analysis Plug-in User Guide](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/SAP_BUSINESSOBJECTS_ANALYSIS_OFFICE/2.8.2.0/en-US)).

The problem is extracting data this way is too time consuming-

1. Waiting time for SAP Analysis Office to return result
2. Excel is limited by the number of rows

I need to extract years of data, let's say 5 year worth of transaction data using this method. And each month, there's approximately 600k records.

For every month I probably have to wait for more than 20 minutes before the SAP system returns any results, and I need to cross fingers that my Excel wouldn't crash. And worst, I pretty much need to query again manually for the next remaining months. It's not practical to sit back and check my laptop every 20 minutes to see whether the query has been completed.

In other words, to extract merely 5 year worth of transaction data using this method, I have to spent at least 20 hours waiting for the queries to complete. Worst is, what if I missed one or more columns required to do the analysis?

Once I have all the monthly data extracted from SAP system through SAP Analysis Office, I want to analyze the data using R.

Hence, I was wondering if there's a more efficient way of extracting this data from R.

Or is there any methods available that I can interact with the SAP system using R.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of SAP are you running?

Comment: @BryanCain not sure, how do you check for SAP version?

Comment: I’m not sure you can check source system version from AO.  You might need to ask your IT team. If your system is running HANA on the backend, you should be able to connect directly from R using JDBC. If you’re not, I’m not sure.

Comment: I'm sure I don't have direct access to HANA. But I can check on that. More importantly, does HANA have the same tables that are available through AO? Is it something I need to check with my SAP team? Currently I have 2 ways to extract data from SAP, either using AO or the gui based NetWeaver.

Comment: @BryanCain unfortunately my SAP Hana has limited access to 3rd party tool, there was some licensing updates apparently. Apparently any 3rd party needs to be connected to other SAP application layers ( BW application – BEx Query, APD etc). Do you know any other way to connect to SAP using R?

Comment: Unless someone writes you a custom extractor or broadcasts you a spreadsheet, no. I think maybe your IT department just doesn’t want to give you access. JDBC connections via r studio are absolutely supported by sap (if you’re on Hana).

Comment: @BryanCain the previous workaround we have was to dump the data from SAP into a SQL database, then I can query from the SQL database. There was an email being circulated recently that SAP Hana can no longer be queried using 3rd party tools due to licensing issue. But at the same time, I'm also quite aware that the SAP HANA is already overwhelmed with queries that the BI team would advise not connect to HANA directly. I'll try again my luck with HANA. Thanks again!